# How do I list all licenses used in a maven project?

Tags: java, maven

I have a multimodule project that has a lot of dependencies.  I want to check which licenses it had at a certain point, and see how many licenses were added since then.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I found these plugins:

1. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/license-mojo.html
2. http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/examples/example-download-licenses.html

But neither of these give me *exactly* what I want.  I have to do a lot of post processing after this.  Is there a more direct way to see the list of licenses used in a maven project?

Comment: http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/examples/example-license-list.html - lists the licenses available. Based on the sample output shown what additional information are you looking for?

Comment: @DROY [The description here](http://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/index.html) is a little ambiguous.  What does it mean for a license to be "available"?  EG: Will it list Apache 2.0 even if I'm not using it?

Comment: Can you check this link and see if this is the sort of report you are looking for? http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/dependencies.html

Comment: It's a bit unclear. How is the `license-maven-plugin` not doing what you want? It does list the licences of all the project dependencies.

Comment: @Tunaki, as I read it the OP wants to see a license history - point in time history.

Comment: You can use your repository manager for that. For example you wan't to have a list of licenses of a project at version 1.0.0 you can download the project pom file and let analyse that via licenses-maven-plugin (via goal download-licenses) and store the resulting file and do the same for next version 1.0.1 or 1.1.0 etc. and that you can make a diff. Out of the box there does not exist such solution but it might be interesting to create such a thing...

Answer (score 6):

I used [License Maven Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/) and its `license:third-party-report` goal to get a pretty nice report.

Answer (score 4):

I've developed a website, https://www.licensediscovery.io, that will help Java developers to find licenses for the artifacts that they and their software are depending on.

Licensediscovery.io enables users to search for Java artifacts by using any of the following syntaxes: Maven, Gradle, SBT, Ivy, Leiningen, Grape, Buildr or plain. Licensediscovery.io will collect, parse and present all identifiable Java artifacts and present them and their licenses in either a table, bar chart, donut chart or a network graph.

You can easily export all Maven dependencies from your project into a plain-format dependency list and use it to search for licenses in LicenseDiscovery.io (An example is available under the 'Documentation'-section on the website). LicenseDiscovery.io will try to find all the artifacts and their corresponding licenses. The result can then be exported into a CSV file. You can download the result on fixed interval and then compare them over time.

Answer (score 1):

Diff'ing, such as khmarbaise suggests, is the most sensible approach. Checkout (or download) the given project at different versions, and run a license report for each version, storing output in filenames based on version, then diff them. This is very much a human-in-the-loop method. Alternatively, write a program that reads a list of "acceptable" licenses, and reports on (hopefully small number of) exceptional, non-compliant licenses. If you write a useful report, be sure to mention it here, in case others may find it useful as well.